# getting a loop result to display in sequence list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program to calculate the distance traveled when you enter the mph in one input box and the hours traveled in another one. When I run the program it just tells me the distance repeated by the number of hours you enter. I need it to display in sequence how many miles per hour. For instance if the user enters 60 mph for 3 hours I want it to display a list that looks like:

1 hr 60 miles
2 hr 120 miles
3 hr 180 miles

here's the code I've written so far:

```
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click

Dim intSpeed As Integer

    Dim intHours As Integer

    Dim intDistance As Integer = 0


    Dim strSpeed As String

    Dim strHours As String

    Dim intCount As Integer = 0

    lstDistance.Items.Clear()
    lstDistance.Items.Add("Hours:        Distance:         ")

    strSpeed = InputBox("Enter speed in miles-per-hour", "Speed")

    'convert to integer

    If Integer.TryParse(strSpeed, intSpeed) Then
        Do Until intCount = 1
            strHours = InputBox("Input hours Traveled", "Hours")
            If Integer.TryParse(strHours, intHours) Then
                intCount += 1
            End If
        Loop
        For intCount = 1 To intHours
            intDistance = intSpeed * intHours
            lstDistance.Items.Add(intHours.ToString & "                   " & intDistance.ToString & " Miles")
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

I know there's a much simpler way to do this but the book I'm learning from specifically asks for you to solve the problem using a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your lstDistance is a listbox.
 you just have to change inthoures to intcount

```
For intCount = 1 To intHours
intDistance = intSpeed * intHours
lstDistance.Items.Add(intHours.ToString & "                   " & intDistance.ToString & " Miles")
Next
```

to

```
For intCount = 1 To intHours
            intDistance = intSpeed * intCount
            lstDistance.Items.Add(intCount.ToString & "                   " & intDistance.ToString & " Miles")
        Next
```

because you want to display the result of every hour you need to use intcount.
then you will get the result you want.
1*60 = 60
2*60 = 120
3*60 = 180

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim intSpeed As Integer

    Dim intHours As Integer

    Dim intDistance As Integer = 0


    Dim strSpeed As String

    Dim strHours As String

    Dim intCount As Integer = 0

    lstDistance.Items.Clear()
    lstDistance.Items.Add("Hours:        Distance:         ")

    strSpeed = InputBox("Enter speed in miles-per-hour", "Speed")

    'convert to integer

    If Integer.TryParse(strSpeed, intSpeed) Then
        Do Until intCount = 1
            strHours = InputBox("Input hours Traveled", "Hours")
            If Integer.TryParse(strHours, intHours) Then
                intCount += 1
            End If
        Loop
        For intCount = 1 To intHours
            intDistance = intSpeed * intCount
            lstDistance.Items.Add(intCount.ToString & "                   " & intDistance.ToString & " Miles")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: that is actually what I came up with after fooling around with it. The only problem is when I put in 60 mph and 5 hrs it comes back with 1 hour 300 miles and so forth instead of 1 hr 60 miles and so forth

Comment: No you were right, I missed that little change you did. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `For` loop.

```
For intCount = 1 To intHours
    intDistance = intSpeed * intHours
    lstDistance.Items.Add(intHours.ToString & "                   " & intDistance.ToString & " Miles")
Next
```

What's the value that's changing?  `intCount`, right?  Are you using `intCount` in the output at all?

Comment: I thought that intCount was being used to display the number of input boxes not the number of hours that was being entered into that input box

Comment: This is a perfect example of what happens when someone tries to write code without knowing what the code is actually supposed to do.  Once the code is written, there's no way to check whether it does what it's supposed to because what it's supposed to do isn't written anywhere.  The number of `InputBoxes`?  The number of `InputBoxes` is two, plain and simple.  One for the speed and one for the time.  You then count from 1 to that time and, for each increment, output the distance travelled up to that time.

Comment: That is a fair comment. I read the chapter in the book and I didn't understand all of it. The way I've got the most out of it so far is to take code from the examples and then fool around with it till it does what I need it to do